# See same database on DataGrip (JetBrains) and MySQL Workbench (import database used in MySQL WB to DAtaGrip)

Tags: mysql, database, datagrip

In the image below you will see that on the right (MySQL WB) I have 2 schemas that do not appear on DataGrip... how can I "import" them?

[image]

Comment: on the left side you see intrbal databaeses that mysql worbench diesb't shiw at that position and as the interval word indicates, you can't import them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on '1 of 5' link next to data source name and select target schemas from the list.